# How many small cubes are removed from the big cube?

Tags: geometry

The maths question as shown in the picture below is from a Mathematics Olympiad exercise booklet for primary school students. The result I calculated was 25 which is option A, but the key wasn't A. In order not to affect your judgement, I will not reveal the key now. Would you please see which other option is right and provide an explanation? Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Comment: I got ${}{}29$.

Comment: Thank you, @AnginaSeng. But how? Would you please explain?

Comment: Several ways, but directly; 2 are removed on the left and right, 15 are removed from top  to bottom then 2 lots of 6 are removed from the front and back. That way you don't count anything twice.

Comment: Thank you, @Paul. In your way of calculating, does that mean there are 29 cubes in all removed?

Comment: 2+15 + 12 = 29 sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3 \times 5 \times 1 + (3 \times 5 \times 1 - 3) + (5 \times 1 \times 1 - 3) = 15 + 12 + 2 = 29$$

The first $3 \times 5 \times 1$ slot contains 15 cubes.

The second $3 \times 5 \times 1$ slot also contains 15 cubes, but since it intersects with the first in 3 cubes, it only adds $15 - 3 = 12$ new cubes.

The final $5 \times 1 \times 1$ slot contains 5 cubes, but it also intersects with the previous in 3 cubes, so it only adds $5 - 3 = 2$ new cubes.

Thus, the result is $15 + 12 + 2 = 29$ cubes.

These problems are much easier, if you try to visualize the inverse.  If you find it too difficult, but have cube-shaped pieces (dice, or better yet, Lego bricks), building these from actual physical objects can help "train" your mind.  It is often fun, too.

Comment: Thank you, @Guest. Some other people here also calculate the result as 29 cubes removed. But the key says it's 48. I can't figure out why. Even if there were no intersected cubes, the total is but 35. Maybe there were something wrong with the key itself. We shall wait a while to see whether there are other opinions showing up. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MichaelMay: The key must be in error.  Consider this: the three sections that are removed, contain $15$, $15$, and $5$ cubes, if removed individually.  But somehow the key claims that they contain 48.  That is impossible, because the combined volume of the removed sections is less than $48$.  Even if we think of this as a pile of dice, so that not-removed-cubes that were supported by the removed sections were also somehow lost, that only adds an additional $8$ cubes, *still* short of the $48$ cubes the key claims.  So, we can safely say that the key is in error.

Comment: Thank you. I fully agree. The maximum of removed cube can only be the sum of the three blocks of cubes described in the question. We cannot stick to the key which can occasinally wrong.

Comment: @MichaelMay: Exactly!  It is good (no, excellent) to consider each answer logically, and not just trust an authority.  If you are not already aware, in engineering and science this becomes an actual tool, [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).  Essentially, when applying some model (formula), you ignore the numbers but use the dimensions/units, and check if what comes out is sensible units for what the model claims to provide.  Programmers often call this kind of checking "sanity checks", too. :)

Comment: Thanks for your introduction. Being a non-engineering person, I've never think of maths or engineering problems from the underlying philosophy. But I can roughly capture what you're talking about. I guess the engineering tool you introduced is a general paradigm which includes the trial-and-error approach to problem solving. Sometimes for solving a problem, logic goes before actual numbers. I'm interested in programming which involves a lot of logic and modeling, so I need to learn more advanced thinking tools for grasping complicated programming concepts. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion.

For clarity, let's say the 1 X 3 X 5 slot at the top is $A$, the 3 X 1 X 5 slot at the front is $B$, and the 1 X 1 X 5 slot at the left is $C$.  We write $|A|$ for the volume of $A$.

If we just add the volumes of the three slots, we have
$$S_1 = |A| + |B| + |C| = 15 + 15 + 5= 35$$
If we add the volumes of pairwise intersections of the slots, we have
$$S_2 = |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C| = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7$$
Finally, the intersection of all three slots is one cube:
$$S_3 = |A \cap B \cap C| = 1$$
By Inclusion / Exclusion, the volume of the union of the three slots is
$$S_1-S_2+S_3 = 29$$

Comment: Thank you, @awkward. That's a very special perspective.